# How do I find a Stronghold

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

When I make a end portal in minecraft XboxOne Edition Winter Upate it doesnt work all of then are facing in lava and everything so I decided to go to a stronghold but I didnt know how to get to one. So i'd like to know how! :-)

Answer (score 0):

To locate a world's Stronghold(s), you must craft Eyes of Ender using 1 Blaze Powder and 1 Ender Pearl in a crafting table or the 2x2 inventory crafting grid. It's better to bring quite a few, as some will likely shatter after use, and you need some to light the End portal, assuming that is your goal. To use an Eye of Ender, press the `UseItem` button on your controller (default is `X`) and it will fly into the sky in the direction of the Stronghold. Repeat this process until the Eye drifts slowly into the ground, and dig down. The Stronghold will be under that location. Good luck and happy hunting!